# kops kubernetes dashboard not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

Have created a kops kubernetes cluster

Installed dashboard using:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/kops/master/addons/kubernetes-dashboard/v1.6.3.yaml
```

Versions

```
kubectl version
```

gives:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.4", GitCommit:"793658f2d7ca7f064d2bdf606519f9fe1229c381", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-17T08:30:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Browsing to:

https://api.k.mydomain.com/ui

Gives:

Error: 'malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"'
Trying to reach: 'http://100.x.x.x:8443/'

How should I access dashboard?

Comment: is the API ELB listern set to 443->443 so it passes through ssl.. or is it set to 443->80 ?

Comment: Mike I didn't think that the api endpoint went to a load balancer

Comment: the default kops install in AWS has it go through a ELB

Comment: An AWS ELB? I have another kops install that maps the API dns directly to the master node.

Comment: Perhaps my install didn't complete. I noticed the api dns name was not created properly by kops.

Comment: generally speaking you do use a route53 address and it should add it to the zone

Answer (score 1):

New versions of dashboard don't work properly with short `/ui` path.
You need to use ugly `/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` instead.

Check the official site for details.
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard